# SSIS csv import - issue with data

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssis-2008

I've got an audit log for PowerBI we are trying to import into our data warehouse. Issue is we can't break the rows up to be under the correct headings with how it is currently formatted. Below is a photo of how it is downloaded. The main issue is that every row doesn't have the same column headers in it. E.g. ItemName isn't in the last two rows of our data.

Downloaded Data:

[image: Downloaded Data]

Example of data not under correct columns

[image]

Comment: You have a problem when there is different delimiters and in fact the result is behind each column (No exact column headers). I would traverse your CSV file with a C# script, and simple read every character. I know this could be a pain, but as i see its the only solutions unless your business can make changes to the CSV file

Comment: A c# script is probably the way to go. However, if the gaps in column data are consistent, meaning the column count is going to be 10, 11 or 12 (or something like that) then you may be able to use a derived column task with the tokencount/token function.

Comment: For example, if your 10th column may or not exist then -
`tokencount([column], ":") == 10 ? token([column], ":", 10) : "")`